# Boto3 - Print AWS Instance Average CPU Utilization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to print out just the averaged CPU utilization of an AWS instance. This code will print out the 'response' but the for loop at the end isn't printing the averaged utilization. Could someone assist? Thank you in advance!

```
    import boto3
    import sys
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
        client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
        response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                'Name': 'InstanceId',
                'Value': 'i-1234abcd'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=datetime(2018, 4, 23) - timedelta(seconds=600),
            EndTime=datetime(2018, 4, 24),
            Period=86400,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            Unit='Percent'
        )
    for cpu in response:
        if cpu['Key'] == 'Average':
            k = cpu['Value']
    print(k)
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\bin\TestCW-CPU.py", line 25, in <module>
        if cpu['Key'] == 'Average':
    TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Include in your post what the data structure "response" contains looks like.

Comment: JordanM,

This is the response I got:

        1.670941576086957

After I used a counter to divide the sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will output the average CPU:

```
    for k, v in response.items():
        if k == 'Datapoints':
        for y in v:
            print(y['Average'])
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for cpu in response['Datapoints']:
  if 'Average' in cpu:
    print(cpu['Average'])

2.25348611111
2.26613194444
```

You can see why this works, if you print the value of `cpu`:

```
print(response)

for cpu in response['Datapoints']:
  print(cpu)

{u'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 23, 23, 50, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'Average': 2.2534861111111106, u'Unit': 'Percent'}
{u'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 23, 50, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'Average': 2.266131944444444, u'Unit': 'Percent'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to filter 'Datapoints' from response and then print average :

```
for cpu in response['Datapoints']:
        print(cpu['Average'])
```

Also, if you want to use a list for mean of all values :

```
# faster code
average = [cpu['Average'] for cpu in response['Datapoints']]
```

The above average list can be used for mean:

```
# if list is not empty
if average:
    print('Mean : ',sum(average)/len(average))
```