# Finding idle EC2 instances using the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

using bash/cli

I have an account that has 50+ running EC2 instances. I would like to locate those instances that do not use more than average 5% of their CPU over a weeks time.

I am aware that I can use get-metric-statistics but should I use a date span of one week and a period of 604800 seconds ?

And how can I print a nice report with the InstanceID in front of each row ? I imagine I can sed my way to prettiness but is there a better way ? jmespath ?

Lastly would this be easier if I did it with Boto3 and Python ?

Comment: this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044759/boto3-print-aws-instance-average-cpu-utilization

Comment: The compute optimizer is a newer service that basically does this. It's a no-cost service: https://aws.amazon.com/compute-optimizer/